# matching webpages keywords to a set of keywords in database

Tags: php, algorithm, wordpress, solr, replace

in my database i've list of say 5000 rows (as keywords). now given an article (may be even 1000 words), i want to match any words matching to keywords in database. for example, i've these records in db (rows are mentioned using comma):
`tv, tv and videos, movie, horror movie, camera, digital camera, canon digital camera`

Each row has another column named 'URL'. And my input string may be like:

> i hate horror movies. Canon releases a new digital camera. So far I own 3 digital cameras...'

from the above string, i need to match:

- **horror movies** against my stored keyword *horror movie*. but i don't want only ***movies*** to be matched against *movie* as **horror movie** keyword is more appropriate here.
- **digital camera** against stored keyword *digital camera*
- **digital cameras...** against stored keyword *digital camera*

(bold phrases exists in the article, italic phrases are in database)

Iteration through each keywords in database may be impossible and unrealistic. so far i've learned Solr may be a fit. but i'm not sure how will I index & query Solr. For querying Solr, I've to provide the keywords. But i do not know what are my keywords. I just know the whole article. A keyword may consists 1 or many words. Totally random, but i can say maximum 5 words.

After matching, i need to replace the keywords in the article with the next column's (URL) value. for example, the keywords in the article **horror movies** need to be replaced with the URL column of the *horror movie*.

can anyone enlighten me with the correct path? any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: hello @PedroFillastre, how do you thing str_replace() may work? can you kindly elaborate? for string replace, i will need to determine my keywords, that's my biggest challenge for me now.

Comment: you can make an array of all your keywords and an other of all your links http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: then how will i do the following things: 1. match **horror movies** against *horror movie*. 2. match **horror movies** but not **movie**?

Comment: @HungryCoder check if in array ??? -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

I think there are actually a few parts to your question but I am to assume that you basically want to submit an article to your website and then your website backend will the process this article and replace all keywords with a bold font and url?

Given that you want to manipulate your article and inject data from your db perhaps a raw php solution would fit the bill (but I must admit I'm not familiar enough with Solr / Lucene to offer advice). You would obviously have to do some benchmarking but 5,000 rows of data is not unreasonable amounts of data to deal with in this type of system as I assume you won't be submitting articles every few seconds or even minutes?

**Therefore you would need to:**

1. Select all your 'keywords' from your database at once, including your url's (to be stored in memory for processing the article).
2. Convert (if required) your keyword data into a multi-dimensional associate array (as it will be easier to deal with if your db query hasn't already done this).
3. Establish your plural variations either in an additional array or perhaps, if they vary from keyword to keyword in an additional column in your db).
4. When you submit your article you have to (one way or other) loop through all 5000 keywords (including additional loops for all plural variations) searching the whole article for said keywords.
5. If any keywords are found in your article you would then obviously need to replace these matches with the bold font and matching url.
6. Then once all keywords in the article have been processed you obviously need to then either save or show this article to the user?

**Two other points regarding your keywords are:**

- Establishing if your plural keywords extend beyond a 's' postfix
  (i.e. are you also trying to match plural words which actually
  change the spelling like, 'buddy' => 'buddies')?
- Grammatically, how far are you prepared / need to go, would you need
  to or want to match things like digital camera's to digital camera?

Sorry for the rather long winded / cryptic answer but I think it's important to understand the full scope of your project before looking for a solution. You may already have these details down but from your question I think there are too many variables to offer a complete answer. I would gladly offer some code samples / further explanation on any of the above points if you require?

**Edit:** Bit confused as you make reference to identifying your keywords, aren't the keywords the words already in your db? Or are you trying to organically create a db of keywords from submitted articles, so your system will harvest your articles for keywords whilst also searching and replacing for currently stored keywords from your db?

Comment: Steve H, thanks for your input. I'm going to explain and answer your questions after a while finishing my current tasks. i appreciate that you've looked at it.

Comment: yes, u got the main idea. however, though initially i gave an example of 5000 records, there is a chance of increase in the count. currently we see a scope of around 50K records. that's why a normal PHP loop will not work. so far i've done the work `preg_replace` and it supports plurals like 's, es' but does not support plurals that changes backwords like 'factory -> factories'. moreover, it doesn't support apostrophes. here is the expression currently i'm using `~{$keyword}(s|es)*\b(?!(.(?<!\[[A-Za-z0-9_-]))*?\[/[A-Za-z0-9_-])(?!(.(?<!\<a))*?\</a)~is`.the expression skips [aa][/aa], <a></a>

Comment: About your confusion: I have the keywords in the databases but when an article, say a blog post, is my input i do not know what keywords i should find from it unless I match against the db. and looping through each keywords that are in db, is impossible when the size of records is 50K+. I also guess Solr will not fit here as here my input is the blog post, not just a keyword to match. for solr, we need to send the keyword to find from our indexes.

Comment: hmm, you said it's impossible to do this in PHP, are you sure about that? PHP will easily handle a loop of 50,000, the question is will your server allow it, i.e. is max_execution_tim et al set high enough. I think you should create a few test scripts (i.e insert 50,000 records into a database and perform a loop on records, and see what happens). You may be jumping to conclusions and giving yourself more problems in doing so. Just looking at your regular expression, I think you might run into trouble doing it this way. Why not process the blog post / article to remove all html....

Comment: and content in between before you try and search for the keywords, will be faster as a) less words to search through (assuming you are looping through the 50k db keywords) and b) will mean you search won't need as complicated search expression. So assuming you now have a clean blog post (with no links / html) I would grab all keywords from db and try a few options to test performance. For example you could do a 2-step process. Perform a full loop using your db keywords, and within the loop do a stripos($content, $keyword) and store any matches in an array to be processed by a preg_replace.

Comment: after the whole db has been processed you will have a much smaller array for your preg_replace and will (*probably) be much quicker than searching the whole article using preg_replace. But again this is just an idea, so further testing would need to be done. In regards to plurals, this is complicated as you need to get this right, I would possibly be tempted to add an extra keyword for the ies varients or you will have to do any additional search/replace for this. I still don't quite get what you mean in regards to blog posts and keywords as even with articles you would be using the same db?

Comment: So you know the keywords as they will be always in the db, so therefore the keywords will always be stored in the db (assuming you can access it). Only other way is to organically determine the keywords for blog posts as and when, but then you would still need a predetermined set of links (so same problem). Sorry I couldn't offer more exact advice, but I would suggest you do a benchmark of 50,000 db keywords to firstly determine if this is achievable before ruling it out. Likewise try a few things and then perhaps post another question on something more specific. I hope you get it solved.

Comment: hi, thanks for your inputs. Yes, that kind of loop is possible by language but it may, probably, be impractical. moreover, the script may run on some shared hostings where such such iterations may be considered as abuse. i believe there are better ideas to implement such scenarios. that's i'm looking. however, for time being, i will try your multi step iterations and benchmark them. thanks